# Poweredge R715 with H700 & SATA drives

Tags: dell-poweredge, sata, raid6, h700

I am taking a class that is all about configuring and deploying physical & virtual servers.  So as to be able to do this more readily I bought a bare-bones Dell Poweredge R715, 2 Opteron 6276s, 64GBs DDR3 ECC Registered RAM, an H700 RAID card, and 6 drive carriers.  For the drives I bought 6 enterprise class 250GB Seagate Constellation.2 SATA drives.

What I was wanting to know is what else, if anything, I will need to get the drives working in a proper RAID6...Or have I already shot myself in the foot by not asking sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, got everything you need. That's a SAS card, the h700.  A SAS bus will take SATA drives, but a SATA bus won't take SAS drives.

All you need to do is configure a raid in the h700 firmware, or by using the OS level config tools for the card. Either will work.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking just wasn't sure if I needed any extra cabling.

Comment: You may have some issues where non Dell branded drives showing amber LEDs (failure indicator) simply because they aren't matching a whitelist on the controller firmware.  The few times I've run across it, the functionality of the RAID still worked fine but I never could find a way to get the fault indicators cleared.

Comment: I've heard that about the H700, but I also heard that this compatibility was fixed in later firmwares.